# A query on 'git clone'

Tags: git

From git-scm book:

> Let’s say you have a Git server on your network at git.ourcompany.com. If you clone from this, Git’s clone command automatically names it origin for you, pulls down all its data, creates a pointer to where its master branch is, and names it origin/master locally. Git also gives you your own local master branch starting at the same place as origin’s master branch, so you have something to work from.

Would this hold true even if in remote we have several branches apart from 'master'. As 'master' is not a special branch, it is just default name of the first branch when we do 'git init'.

So why would cloning remote repository create pointer to position of only 'master' branch?

Comment: By the way, I suggest editing a condensed form of the question into the title line, e.g., *why does cloning create only master branch?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Would this hold true even if in remote we have several branches apart from 'master'.

Generally, yes.

> As 'master' is not a special branch, it is just default name of the first branch when we do 'git init'.

That's also correct.

> So why would cloning remote repository create pointer to position of only 'master' branch?

`git clone url directory` is a convenient shorthand for the following steps:

1. `mkdir directory` (and then all subsequent steps happen inside *`directory`*, although your own command-shell remains outside it so that *you* have to `cd directory` afterward);
2. `git init`;
3. run any `git config`s necessary based on additional clone options (e.g., `--bare` or `--mirror` set `core.bare`; there are many possibilities here);
4. `git remote add origin url` (or some other name than `origin` if you have set the `-o` option);
5. `git fetch`;
6. and finally, `git checkout master` (or `git checkout` some other name if you have set the `-b` option, or in one other case).

It's this final `git checkout` step that creates your local `master` branch.  Note that this does not depend on the number of branches in the remote.  It does, however, depend on the remote *having* a `master` branch.

When you ask `git checkout` to check out a branch that does not exist yet in your own repository, instead of immediately failing with an error message saying "you don't have that branch", Git looks at all of your *remote-tracking names*, such as `origin/develop` and `origin/master`.  In the six-step process above, those names were created by `git fetch`, which copied all of the branch names in the other Git at *`url`*.  Thus, if *they* have the two branches `develop` and `master`, your clone now has the two remote-tracking names `origin/develop` and `origin/master`.

Git scans through those remote-tracking names.  One of them resembles `master`.  Git, in effect, says to itself: *Aha, you did not just mean "check out existing `master`", you meant "create new `master` based on `origin/master`", **then** check out `master`.*

That's why cloning the remote repository creates only `master`: you only *asked* it to `git checkout master`.

Now, I mentioned above the `-b` option, plus one other case.  If you run `git clone -b develop url directory*`, you tell your Git to run `git checkout develop` at the end instead.  So you will create your own `develop` based on `origin/develop`.

If you *don't* use `-b`, your own Git asks their Git: *Which branch do you recommend checking out?*  The *default* answer is `master`, which is why you usually end up with `git checkout master`.  But their Git can supply a different name.  Web services like GitHub and Bitbucket offer web interfaces to set this.  If you're running a corporate server, it's up to you to set it yourself (the trick is to set the symbolic `HEAD` name in the server-side bare repository).  If you are just using someone else's setup, don't worry about it: you cannot control their Git, but you do have *your* `-b` option when you run `git clone`.

Comment: Thanks for detailed answer. I have a query. It is very much possible that when remote repo was created, its creator named default branch other than 'master'. So won't this cause problems as git looks for master.

Comment: No: if the remote Git recommends that your client Git check out branch `abc`, the remote Git necessarily has also sent your client Git branch `abc`, which your own Git has renamed to `origin/abc`. You, via your `-b` argument or lack thereof, control which branch you ask your Git to check out; if you don't supply `-b master` your Git uses their recommendation and checks out `abc`, which they have supplied and your Git has called `origin/abc` and therefore you end up on your own `abc`, pointing to the same commit as your `origin/abc` which is the same commit as their `abc`.